# boost::asio - is it possible to bind to a local device (equivalent of SO_BINDTODEVICE) rather than local address?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I would like to bind to a local interface, eg `"eth0"`, using `boost::asio`.

The equivalent code using the low level socket interface would be:

```cpp
const std::string ifc = "eth0";

struct ifreq ifr;
bzero(&ifr, sizeof(ifr));
memcpy(ifr.ifr_name, ifc.c_str(), ifc.length());
if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, static_cast<void*>(&ifr), sizeof(ifr)) < 0)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("bind to local interface failed");
}
```

However, when I attempt to pass a local interface to the `boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver`, it can't resolve it:

```cpp
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

const std::string ifc = "eth0";

auto ctx = socket.get_executor();
tcp::resolver resolver(ctx);
tcp::resolver::results_type results = resolver.resolve(ifc, "");
```

This throws an exception, with description `"Host not found (authoritative)"`

By the content of the error message it does sound like it's attempting to resolve the interface as a host address.

Is it possible to do the equivalent of `SO_BINDTODEVICE` using `boost::asio`?

Comment: "it does sound like it's attempting to resolve the interface as a host address" - that's also what it is documented to do. Why are you resolving it, whereas you didn't in the "low level socket interface" snippet?

Comment: I'll be honest, I find the boost documentation increadibly unhelpful and unilluminating, so don't really know if I should be using the resolver or not. How would I create an asio `endpoint` which points to the local interface which I could then pass to `bind`?

Comment: You weren't using it in the lowlevel version, that's a good sign. Of course, I didn't check that the lowlevel version works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to do the equivalent of SO_BINDTODEVICE using boost::asio?

No, but you can use the option like you're used to.

```
if (setsockopt(socket.native_handle(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, static_cast<void*>(&ifr), sizeof(ifr)) < 0)
```

You could also define your own custom option to make it "prettier", but I would probably only do this if this is somehow oft-repeating code.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I guess I can reach down into the native layer below as you've suggested